Show that the proper transform of complex submanifold along blowup is also complex submanifold.
Suppose $X$ is a complex manifold, and $N_1, N_2$ are complex submanifolds of $X$.
Assume that $N_1 \cap N_2 \ne N_1$ is also a complex submanifold, and $N_2 \setminus N_1 \ne \emptyset.$
Now, blow up $X$ along $N_1$. Then, we could define the proper transform $\widetilde{N_2}$ of $N_2$ as the topological closure of $N_2 \setminus N_1$ in $\operatorname{Bl}_{N_1}(X)$.
Then, is $\widetilde{N_2}$ also a complex submanifold of $\mathrm{Bl}_{N_1}(X)$? If we use a techniques in analytic geometry, similar to algebraic geometry, then it's obviously yes(At least, I guess, projective case..). But, what I really want is a differential geometric proof, which is exactly equivalent to show the existence of complex embedding.
Outline of the idea of the proof

Since $N_1 \cap N_2$ is a complex submanifold of $X$,we could choose a complex coordinate near $N_1 \cap N_2$ that splits into horizontal part and normal part.
Then, we could blowup with respect to this coordinate,
Finally, analyze the closure of $N_2$, and get local descriptions of embedding.

Is this approach viable? If there are references, books, articles that handle the proper transform in differential geometrical setting, it would be greatly appreciated. I would like to check what's really going on. I've already checked Huybrechts, Voisin, Griffith-Harris, but they don't contain it.

You keep saying differential geometry. All you mean is to view things as complex manifolds, and work in local holomorphic coordinates. (There's nothing to do with metrics or connections here.) What is the difficulty in what you propose? Is it not a completely local question along the exceptional divisor?

@TedShifrin Indeed, you're absolutely right. It's really simple because this problem is just a toy model of a more complex one I have in mind. I'm already attempting the computation, but I thought detailed references on better local representations might be helpful. Specifically, precise formulas for charts and embeddings would be valuable for future work.
